# Css inline style as an attribute in React component

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have custom component in which i map attributes.
In this component I have label which have css class assigned.
But i also want optional inline style for this label.
The problem is that in react I need to surround inline style with curly braces and i can't escape them or set them correctly in component. How to resolve this?

Code from component:

```
const CustomComponent = ({items, name}) => (
    <fieldset>
        {items
            .map((item, index) => ({item, id: `${name || 'dod'}-${item.value || index}`}))
            .map(({item, id}) =>
                <div key={id}
                     className="className1">
                    <input
                        id={id}
                        name={name}
                        type="text"
                    />
                    <label htmlFor={id} className="className" style={item.style}>
                        {item.label}
                    </label>
                </div>
            )}
    </fieldset>
);
```

Code from rendered .jsx

```
  <CustomComponent             
       name="name"
       items={[{
           value: 'value',
           label: 'label',
           style: {{display: 'inline'}}      -> not working
       }]}
  />
```

Comment: Can you show us more code ? what is the type of `item.style` ? It must be an object literal ? if you are mapping, use `key`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to include the first `{}` when you are directly inside a `Virutal DOM Object`. `<... items={object} .../>` and then object should be written exactly the same way as other `Object Literals`. That being said you need `{display: 'inline'}` instead of `{{display: 'inline'}}` in

```
<CustomComponent             
   name="name"
   items={[{
       value: 'value',
       label: 'label',
       style: {{display: 'inline'}}      -> not working //use {display: 'inline'}
   }]}
/>
```

I've made a pen for this in `Codepen`, you can check it [Here](http://codepen.io/Noctisdark/pen/GWKZaa).

Comment: Glad to be of use.

Answer (score 1):

Your style property have to be an object literal, something like so :

```
item.style = {
 display: 'inline'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In react you can define your styles in form of JS objects, something like

```
  style: {{display: 'inline'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can abstract this further and have a JS file holding all the styles for your page:

```
const styles = {
  myElement: {
    display: 'inline'
  }
}
```

then in the code...

```
<Component style={styles.myElement} />
```